# Python: typeerrors, numbers that are not integers, and variable problems

Tags: python, string, variables, int

So im trying to make a program that asks for 3 numbers and then returns the product of those numbers (determining the volume of a cuboid)

```
def cuboid ():
    A = input('Height '),
    B = input('Width '),
    C = input('Depth '),
```

So far this makes PYthon ask for the three values, but i don't know hot to tell python that they are not strings, but integers. i.e. i don't know how to use the `int()` command. 
so if after that I type: `Volume = A*B*C`it gives a TypeError because he thinks that 1,2 and 3 are not integers.

I don't know why it doesn't work that way, because a rough

```
def o3 (x,y,z):
    print x*y*z
```

does work. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using  `input()` where you should be using `raw_input()`. After the input, you then just need to say `a = int(a)` and a will be an integer which you can do normal arithmetic on.

**example:**

```
def get_cube_dims():
    x = int( raw_input('Enter x:') )
    y = int( raw_input('Enter y:') )
    z = int( raw_input('Enter z:') )
    print 'The volume is: {}'.format(x*y*z)
```

Comment: No, he's using Python 2 (see the `print` statement), and that's precisely why his approach "works" - `input()` in Python 2 evaluates the input string as a Python expression.

Comment: Like this: `def cuboid ():
     A = input('Height '),
     B = input('Width '),
     C = input('Depth '),
     A = int(A)
     B = int(B)
     C = int(C)
     print A*B*C` ? Doesnt work either

Comment: @Javicobos I've added a basic example

Comment: @Javicobos "Doesnt work"? We can better help if you tell us the exception including traceback.

Comment: @JonClements Your example works, mine gave a typeerror. I was using input instead of raw_input, which i should have used. I think that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
def input_int(text):
    while True:
        x = raw_input('%s: ' % text) 
        try:
            return int(x)
        except Exception, e:
            print 'Please enter a correct integer'


h = input_int('Height')
l = input_int('Length')
w = input_int('Width')

print 'Result is', h * l * w
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you where wanting?

```
def cuboidv ():
    h=input('enter hieght')
    l=input('enter length')
    w=input('enter width')
    ans=l*w*h
    print ans
```

Comment: You should never use `input()` (in Python 2) in the first place. You can execute arbitrary code with that, not a good idea to let your users do that.

Comment: `__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')` would surely be a fine input to `input()`.

Comment: @glglgl: Yeah, fun, isn't it?

Comment: @TimPietzcker For an appropriate definition of fun, it is.

Comment: The commas after the first lines made it not work. That was it all; three commas...

Comment: @Javicobos: Because of the comma after your function call. That transformed the single integer value into a tuple - which can't be multiplied with another tuple.